# Java Socket - Sending SSL Segments - How to suppress?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, segment

I want to send a message via a `java.net.Socket`.

The message is: `001C020000C0154C000404850D9583CC00000004560B00E42080004C`

For my application I need this message to be sent via one `TCP packet`.

But checking Wireshark what is happening is, I can see, that it divides the message into 
two reassembled SSL segments:

1. 00
2. 1C020000C0154C000404850D9583CC00000004560B00E42080004C

How can I supress this behavior?

My code is:

```
OutputStream os = m_sslsocket.getOutputStream();
os.flush();
write(hex2Byte("001C020000C0154C000404850D9583CC00000004560B00E42080004C");
os.flush();
```

where `hex2Byte` converts the hexadecimal String to a bytearray.

**EDIT**:
Thank you for your comments.

In any case my protocol stack when observing via WireShark looks as follows:
[image]

As you can see there are two SSL Segments, where one is with 00 
and the other has the rest.
How to supress it such, that there is only one segment?

The above is the result of my writing to the outputstream.

(Do not worry about the red. That is just because of IP checksum offload to the network device.)

Comment: What do you mean with "TCP packet" and "SSL segment"? Your question does not really make sence, since TCP is stream oriented and not packet oriented. Even if your TCP stream is segmented into several *IP* packets, this should have absolutely no impact on the receiving end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For my application I need this message to be sent via one TCP packet.

Bad luck, TCP cannot be made to do that reliably, with or without SSL. Adjust your expectations. It's a byte-stream protocol.

Comment: For some reason this did not work on Winx64.
It seems to be a hardware problem. It worked on winx86.

Comment: @Byron-LimTimothySteffan So you got lucky. Don't count on it.